# "Rake/rdoc task is obsolete" message ... and none of the fixes online here are working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a Rails & Ruby noob and was going through the Agile Web Development with Rails book. I did a routine rake command and got this familiar message:

ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (ava
ilable in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
c:/rails_projects/depot/Rakefile:8:in `'

I searched Google thoroughly, tried editing my Gemfile a couple of times as suggested in other threads, updated rdoc gem, and still I get this error. I am running Rails 3.0.5, Ruby 1.9.3p392, rdoc 4.0.2. This is my bundle install:

Using rake (10.0.4)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.5)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Using activemodel (3.0.5)

Using erubis (2.6.6)

Using rack (1.2.8)

Using rack-mount (0.6.14)

Using rack-test (0.5.7)

Using tzinfo (0.3.37)

Using actionpack (3.0.5)

Using mime-types (1.22)

Using polyglot (0.3.3)

Using treetop (1.4.12)

Using mail (2.2.19)

Using actionmailer (3.0.5)

Using arel (2.0.10)

Using activerecord (3.0.5)

Using activeresource (3.0.5)

Using json (1.7.7)

Using bundler (1.3.4)

Using thor (0.14.6)

Using railties (3.0.5)

Using rails (3.0.5)

Using rdoc (4.0.1)

Using sqlite3 (1.3.7)

And my Gemfile:

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'rdoc', ">= 4.0.1"
require 'rdoc/task'

I put that gem rdoc thing in based on one forum I found.

Answer (score 0):

The bad `require 'rake/rdoctask'` call is happening in Rails itself.  The simplest solution is probably to update Rails.  You should be able to work through that book just fine using Rails 3.0.20.